# Create a TypeSpec from an existing file with kotlinpoet

Tags: kotlin, annotations, annotation-processor, kotlinpoet

I need to make a copy of the class marked with my annotation, and then add my own code to it.

***Class marked with my annotation:***

```
@MyAnnotation
class Test {
    private name = "Ann"

    fun method1() {
        println("Test")
    }
}
```

***Generated class:***

```
class Test {
    private name = "Ann"

    fun method1() {
        println("Test")
    }

    fun method2() {
        println("This method was generated")
    }
}
```

So far, I see only one way: go through all the fields, methods, etc. in an existing class and add them to **TypeSpec. ClassBuilder()**, but this is too difficult, I think.

**Is there an easier way, maybe a library?**